# How should I store users in firebase database using their locations as keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose each user has a location (latitude & longitude in decimal degrees format) besides other credentials such as email, etc.

I save every user's account info in the `users` table in database like so:

[image]

where the string "W9ulK6s..." is a user's `uid`, once you click on the `+` sign, you will see the detailed info about this user

Since a user can see other users who are geographically near him/her, I think I should save another copy of each user in a table called `users_location`, this way, I could filter users based on their location without having to go through every single user in the database.

However, I don't know what I should do at this point, firebase does not allow a key to have `.` in it, therefore, I cannot use latitude or longitude as keys, for example, I CANNOT do something like this: suppose the current user's location is (40.1234566, -80.1234567), latitude and longitude

```
    users_location
        40.1234567    // this path contains ".", which is not allowed
            -80.1234567 // neither is this path
                W9ulK6sUXnVq6VVOlSWhRoVjS6t2
                    email: "stack@overflow.com"
                    photoURL: "https://stackoverflow.com"
                    ... // Other credentials
```

So, what should the structure of this `users_location` look like so that I can still filter users by their locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a low likelihood that two coordinates would be exactly the same considering how many decimal places you have on that. The proper way to do this is to simply store the users, give the user a location in their keys.

```
users
   W9ulK6sUXnVq6VVOlSWhRoVjS6t2
   email: "stack@overflow.com"
   photoURL: "https://stackoverflow.com"
   latitude: 40.1234567,
   longitude: -80.1234567,
   ... // Other credentials
```

I would then do a query on this path something like this. The only difficulty with this is that you just can't query by both, you have to query by one or the other then go through the queries client side to figure out what you actually need.

```
ref.child('users').orderByChild('latitude').equalTo(40.1234567);
....
results = data.filter((item) => { item.longitude === -80.1234567});
```

Firebase doesn't work very well when you want to query by multiple fields. The new Firestore, however, does allow you to query on more than one thing, but that product is currently in beta.

Comment: Thank you @Ramzi C., but wouldn't this be too slow? What if there are 1 million users? Because I'm selecting all of them and sort them by their latitude first

Comment: Firebase has a behaviour where 'ordering' is actually quite fast. I do not know how the system itself handles it, but it likely has some sort of indexing magic.